# Highcharts setExtreme is destroying my trigger events

Tags: javascript, angularjs, highcharts

I´m using the ng-highcharts with angularjs.
I have two ways of manipulating the Extremes in my chart:
1. When I´m in the chart selecting or using the navigator.
In the config-Object:

```
xAxis: {
                                events: {
                                    setExtremes: function(e){
                                        if(e.trigger) {
                                            console.log(e.min);
                                        }
                                        }
                                }}
```

and 2nd (when i press a button and want to manipulate through a button):

```
var chart = Highcharts.charts[0];
chart.xAxis[0].setExtremes(start, end);
```

Now the problem is that The 2nd function is destroying the first one.
Means: The first one is working and giving me e.g. the min-value via e.min, but when calling the 2nd function and I want to trigger events in my chart again, the e.min is null (NaN).
Can someone help me, I need both possibilities.

Comment: Is that defined as global param?

Comment: nope, they´re both in their own function

Comment: You can try to extract min value from xAxis object. Reference: this.getExtremes().min or this.min